# Maven Profile does not run appropriate tests

Tags: maven

I have configured a profile for running only integration tests but it is still running all tests. 
This is the configuration:

```
    <profile>
        <id>integration</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I tried with regex like explained at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html but I got this not working.
How do I get only tests running that end with IT.java?

Comment: First would be to use maven-failsafe-plugin instead of the maven-surefire-plugin. Both plugins have appropriate naming schemas (*Test.java, *TestCase.java, Test*.java for surefire whereas for [failsafe: *IT.java etc.](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes)). Apart from that running intgration tests at the test phase is wrong, cause there exist an integration-test life cycle phase which is exactly intended for this. Furthermore help here it's best having the full pom file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not reconfigured the surefire run, but instead added another one to the lifecycle. That way, surefire:test runs twice, once with default execution id (`default-test`) and once with your new execution (`integration-test`)

If you simply want to change the tests being run, you could use:

```
<profile>
    <id>integration</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Which would only reconfigure the *existing* execution.

Still, as khmarbaise already wrote in a comment, it makes much more sense to simply use the `maven-failsafe-plugin`. If you really wanted to skip normal unit test (why would you want that, anyway?), you could explicitly disable surefire in your profile (using `skipTests`-configuration).

Comment: Hi, thanks both of you guys for the helo. @blackbuild: no, I don't want to remove unittesting. Running mvn test should run only unittests, "mvn test -PsoapUi" should run integrated soapUi-Tests and "mvn test -Pintegration" should run only tests ending with IT. I removed the execution added and got it running.